# Where is the mistake in calculating distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let be $X$ random variable with distribution function $F(x)=(1-x^{-a})1_{x>1}\,, a>0$ I want to determine the distribution $Y:=log(X)$
My attempt:
$$\mathbb P(Y \le x)= \mathbb P(log(X)\le x)=\mathbb P(X \le e^x)$$
then I calculated the derivative and plug in:
$$F'(e^x)=\int_0^{e^z}ax^{-a-1}=-e^{-az}+0$$
But this would be negative for any $z$. And so there is a mistake! But what I am doing wrong? Is my lower border wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to apply the definition of cumulative distribution function, i.e.,
$$ F(x) = \mathbb{P}(X\le x), $$
to get
$$ \mathbb{P}(X\le e^x) = F(e^x) = (1-(e^x)^{-a}) 1_{{e^x}>1} = 1-e^{-ax}. $$

Just a comment on what you did: it is *almost* correct (but the left-hand side is $F(e^x)$ and not $F'(e^x)$, as you wrote, and you have to change the $x$ with $z$ in the integral). You have just to remind the fact that there is an indicator function (that is, $1_{x > 1}$) into the definition of $F$, hence your integral starts at $x = 1$ and not at $x=0$, becoming
$$ \mathbb{P}(X \le e^x) = \int_1^{e^x} a z^{-a-1} dz = 1-e^{-ax}. $$